# Python: how to create a colorbar based on a list of values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have to fill some patches with certain color based on given values. I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
df:

   Val  Patch
0   12  0
1   13  1
2   16  2
3   18  3
4   19  4
5   24  5
6   31  6
7   33  7
8   34  8
9   35  9
```

I would like to know how to create associate to each values the "right" color in a colorbar (of reds for instance).

`cmap = plt.cm.Reds`

Comment: Maybe help [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41521016/2901002)

Comment: @jezrael in this case I have to sort `df` based on `df.val`, right?

Comment: It seems yes, I am not sure.